Google Sheets : Filter Without Affecting Columns Outside The Filter
In Google Sheets, if I setup a filter or filter view, the filter affects columns not included in the filter range.
How do I apply the filter to the columns within the range of the filter only?
Example
In the below images, if I filter A from column A, then row 3 disappears entirely — including in columns E-G, despite them being outside of the filter range.




There's no option to restrict the filter to only apply to rows within the filtered range. This post goes into more detail regarding it. One workaround is to stack the tables on top of one another instead of placing them side by side.
